# Converting a long byte array to float array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've a big byte array (4*4096 bytes) containing floats, coming from the serial port. I'd like to convert it to float32 array in Javascript. I'm not really proficient in JS, what I've found is getFloat32 examples and it seems I'd need a for cycle to go through the entire byte buffer, incremented by 4 and convert each step. Is there an easier way (one step) using maybe foreach? Thanks.

Comment: "_I've a big byte array (4*4096 bytes) containing floats, coming from the serial port._" - how are you currently storing this byte array? What is the intermediate step? Or, is it a stream of bytes? What have you attempted?

Comment: The only way to *really* have a "byte array" in JavaScript is to have a typed array, either `Int8Array` or `UInt8Array`. If you're starting from a *string*, there are going to be problems, because the source bytes are going to be interpreted as Unicode code points.

Comment: @Randy Casburn I receiving bytes in a Buffer object, containing 16384 bytes. That's what the serialport lib in nodejs gives me.

Comment: You should investigate [Float32Array typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) - if your Buffer is an ArrayBuffer, you can create it in one step with the constructor -> [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array/Float32Array#examples)

Comment: Note that it's *possible* that you'll run into byte-ordering problems if you base a new `Float32Array` on a buffer that came from "outer space". That should be easy to determine however, and reversing the individual floats as necessary is fairly easy. That's not really that large of an array, and almost any modern CPU can do that sort of work very quickly.

Comment: @Randy Casburn Thank you for your help, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Pointy thank you, I'll check the order of bytes.